# Angularjs & PHP Login

Tags: php, angularjs, login-control

I'm new to angularjs, I'm bit confused about Login Process.

Everytime I log in I'm redirected to the specific page. Which is set already in the code.

I just want to check if the user is logged in. If yes then redirect to --Home--
if not logged in redirect to --Login Again--

What should I use for this?

I heard about local storage. SessionStorage, I'm not familiar with them.
Tell me which way I can manage Login?

Here is my controller for Login

```
app.controller('AngularLoginController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {   
    $scope.loginForm = function() {         
            $http.post("login.php", {
            'email' :$scope.inputData.email,
            'password':$scope.inputData.password
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);                  
                if ( data == 'correct') {
                window.location.href = 'welcome_dashboard.php';
                } 
            else {
                $scope.errorMsg = "Invalid Email and Password";
            }
        })
        }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **$cookieStore** of angular js

> after successfull login you can put login true

```
$cookieStore.put('login', true);
```

and check in your dashboard controller if **$cookieStore.get('login')** undefined than redirect on login page

When you logout you need to remove this cookie **$cookieStore.remove('login')**

if you user **routerprovider** than use **resolve** it's easy to check login or not here one simple example of **resolve**

```
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            controller: 'dashboardController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/dashboard.html',
            resolve:{loggedIn:onlyLoggedIn}
         })
 }

var onlyLoggedIn = function ($location,$q,$cookieStore,$rootScope) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (typeof ($cookieStore.get("login")) === "undefined") {
        deferred.reject();
        window.location.href = 'login.html';
    }else{
        $rootScope.display = true;
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise;

};
```

Comment: You might not be logged in anymore. E.g. the session expired.

Comment: where to keep this onlyLoggedIn function? controller ?

Comment: what's issue you face now?

Answer (score 0):

You'd only use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` if you had a token, for example if you were authenticating using OAuth.

In your case you'll probably be using cookies and sessions. So for this scenario you'd want to have someway of checking if you're authenticated (as your session or cookie might have expired).

I'd create a new endpoint e.g. `current_user.php` that returns true or false (or even the current user details) if you're logged in or not. And then you'd want to call this before any requests that expect the user to be authenticated).

You'll also want to handle any requests that return data that require the user to be authenticated with a `fail` callback that also redirect the user should you get a 401 back.